# Radixv3 with Ssl authentication

Tags: go, redis

```
  "github.com/mediocregopher/radix/v3"
```

for redis connection in my golang project using

```
dialFuncAuthOnly := func(network, addr string) (radix.Conn, error) {
        return radix.Dial(network, addr,dialOpts[1:]...)
```

Now i want to enable ssl for the redis conection